# Need help with the recurrence relation.

Tags: recurrence-relations, special-functions, bessel-functions

everyone. While solving a diagonalization problem I have arrived at the following recurrence relation
$$f_{n}=\Big(\frac{2n}{z}-\lambda\Big)f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}$$
I know that in the case $\lambda=0$ such a recurrence relation is solved by the Bessel functions $f_{n}=J_{n}(z)$. Maybe anyone knows whether there are any special functions solving the recurrence relation for the non-zero $\lambda$? If not, then can anyone suggest any place to look at? Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Is $f_n = f_n(z)$ and $n, \lambda$ parameters?

Comment: $\lambda$ and $z$ are parameters, $n$ is a variable. you need to find a function $f_{n}(z, \lambda)$ such that $f_{n}(z, \lambda)=\Big(\frac{2n}{z}-\lambda\Big)f_{n-1}(z, \lambda)-f_{n-2}(z, \lambda)$

Answer (score 3):

The Bessel functions $J_n(z)$ and $K_n(z)$ satisfy the recursion
$$ f_n(z) = \frac{2(n-1)}{z} f_{n-1}(z) - f_{n-2}(z)$$
Thus $J_{n+1 -\lambda z/2}(z) $ and $K_{n+1-\lambda z/2}(z)$ satisfy
your recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n=\int_a^be^{ns}K(s)~ds$ ,

Then $\int_a^be^{ns}K(s)~ds=\left(\dfrac{2n}{z}-\lambda\right)\int_a^be^{(n-1)s}K(s)~ds-\int_a^be^{(n-2)s}K(s)~ds$

$\dfrac{2n}{z}\int_a^be^{-s}e^{ns}K(s)~ds-\int_a^be^{ns}K(s)~ds-\lambda\int_a^be^{-s}e^{ns}K(s)~ds-\int_a^be^{-2s}e^{ns}K(s)~ds=0$

$\dfrac{2}{z}\int_a^be^{-s}K(s)~d(e^{ns})-\int_a^be^{ns}K(s)~ds-\lambda\int_a^be^{-s}e^{ns}K(s)~ds-\int_a^be^{-2s}e^{ns}K(s)~ds=0$

$\dfrac{2}{z}\left[e^{(n-1)s}K(s)\right]_a^b-\dfrac{2}{z}\int_a^be^{ns}~d(e^{-s}K(s))-\int_a^be^{ns}K(s)~ds-\lambda\int_a^be^{-s}e^{ns}K(s)~ds-\int_a^be^{-2s}e^{ns}K(s)~ds=0$

$\dfrac{2}{z}\left[e^{(n-1)s}K(s)\right]_a^b-\dfrac{2}{z}\int_a^be^{ns}(e^{-s}K'(s)-e^{-s}K(s))~ds-\int_a^be^{ns}K(s)~ds-\lambda\int_a^be^{-s}e^{ns}K(s)~ds-\int_a^be^{-2s}e^{ns}K(s)~ds=0$

$\dfrac{2}{z}\left[e^{(n-1)s}K(s)\right]_a^b-\dfrac{2}{z}\int_a^be^{ns}\left(e^{-s}K'(s)+\left(\dfrac{z}{2}+\dfrac{\lambda z-2}{2}e^{-s}+\dfrac{z}{2}e^{-2s}\right)K(s)\right)~ds=0$

$\therefore e^{-s}K'(s)+\left(\dfrac{z}{2}+\dfrac{\lambda z-2}{2}e^{-s}+\dfrac{z}{2}e^{-2s}\right)K(s)=0$

$e^{-s}K'(s)=-\left(\dfrac{z}{2}+\dfrac{\lambda z-2}{2}e^{-s}+\dfrac{z}{2}e^{-2s}\right)K(s)$

$\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}=-\dfrac{z}{2}e^s-\dfrac{\lambda z-2}{2}-\dfrac{z}{2}e^{-s}$

$\int\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}~ds=\int\left(-z\cosh s-\dfrac{\lambda z-2}{2}\right)~ds$

$\ln K(s)=-z\sinh s-\dfrac{(\lambda z-2)s}{2}+c_1$

$K(s)=ce^{-z\sinh s-\frac{(\lambda z-2)s}{2}}$

$\therefore f_n=\int_a^bce^{\frac{(2n-\lambda z+2)s}{2}-z\sinh s}~ds$

But since the above procedure in fact suitable for any complex number $s$ ,

$\therefore f_n=\int_{a_m}^{b_m}c_me^{\frac{(2n-\lambda z+2)k_mt}{2}-z\sinh k_mt}~d(k_mt)=k_mc_m\int_{a_m}^{b_m}e^{\frac{(2n-\lambda z+2)k_mt}{2}-z\sinh k_mt}~dt$

For some $n$-independent real number choices of $a_m$ and $b_m$ and $n$-independent complex number choices of $k_m$ such that:

$\lim\limits_{t\to a_m}e^{\frac{(2n-\lambda z+2)k_mt}{2}-z\sinh k_mt}=\lim\limits_{t\to b_m}e^{\frac{(2n-\lambda z+2)k_mt}{2}-z\sinh k_mt}$

$\int_{a_m}^{b_m}e^{\frac{(2n-\lambda z+2)k_mt}{2}-z\sinh k_mt}~dt$ converges

One of the choice involving

$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\frac{i(2n-\lambda z+2)t}{2}-iz\sin t}~dt$

$=\int_{-\pi}^0e^{\frac{i(2n-\lambda z+2)t}{2}-iz\sin t}~dt+\int_0^\pi e^{\frac{i(2n-\lambda z+2)t}{2}-iz\sin t}~dt$

$=\int_{-\pi}^0e^{\frac{i(2n-\lambda z+2)(-t)}{2}-iz\sin(-t)}~d(-t)+\int_0^\pi e^{\frac{i(2n-\lambda z+2)t}{2}-iz\sin t}~dt$

$=\int_0^\pi e^{-\frac{i(2n-\lambda z+2)t}{2}+iz\sin t}~dt+\int_0^\pi e^{\frac{i(2n-\lambda z+2)t}{2}-iz\sin t}~dt$

$\propto\int_0^\pi\cos\left(\dfrac{(2n-\lambda z+2)t}{2}-z\sin t\right)~dt$

$\propto\mathbf{J}_\frac{2n-\lambda z+2}{2}(z)$ (according to http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.10)